# Change GUI in Java game

Tags: java, 2d, gui

I'm making a 2D Server/Client game, I have very little to no problems with the server but now I want to work on the client side code.
I'm thinking about using a JFrame and all the other GUI classes/methods.
My question is how do I change the GUI and all things that are displayed.
For example if the user opens the client I want him to login or register, if they logged in I want the client to display the game. Do I just display the new elements and delete the old or is there a other solution? I don't want to use 2 frames.

Comment: You should look at the concept of 'Game states' and change the content of your jframe regarding the current state. You could create one JPane for all of your state and load them in your JFrame as you need them.